# How to generate ocp 4.10 token?

Tags: token, openshift-origin

I'm trying to get the ocp token by http request

I'm trying to run this URL
`/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/serviceaccounts/Bearer/token`

and keep getting this

```
    "reason": "Forbidden",
    "details": {
        "name": "Bearer",
        "kind": "serviceaccounts"
    },
    "code": 403
```